# Problem with Azure AD authentication - Bearer token returns only app information

Tags: php, azure, curl, microsoft-graph-api

I have a problem implementing Azure AD SSO for my website.

The Azure AD configuration uses a certificate instead of a secret. Everything looks to be working, but `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token` returns a Bearer token which contains only app information and I'm trying to get the user information for the user who has logged in.

Can anyone provide me some information and tips how to obtain user information?

Code for getting Bearer token:

```php
public function getAccessToken(){
    $link = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{$this->tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    $request_headers = array(
        'Accept: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    );
    $post_data = array(
        "client_id" => $this->clientId,
        "grant_type" => "client_credentials",
        "client_assertion_type" => "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer",
        "client_assertion" => $this->jwToken,
        "scope" => "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
        "code" => $this->responseCode,
        "redirect_uri" => $this->redirectUri,
    );
    $curlResponse = $this->sendCURLRequest($link, $request_headers, $post_data);
    var_export($curlResponse);
}
```

Comment: To get user info in the token, you need to authenticate the current user with e.g. authorization code flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow.

Comment: Yes, I have done it in `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`. It returns code with whom I query to /token to get Bearer token

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to get the token? If you exchange the code for a token it should contain user info..

Comment: Sure, I edited post and added code which I use for getting Bearer token

Comment: Yeah, your `grant_type` is wrong at least in that one as pointed out in the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @juunas suggested, you should use [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) rather than [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

Now that you have got the `code` from [Request an authorization code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code), next you need to [Redeem a code for an access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#redeem-a-code-for-an-access-token).

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read
&code=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq3n8b2JRLk4OxVXr...
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&grant_type=authorization_code
&code_verifier=ThisIsntRandomButItNeedsToBe43CharactersLong 
&client_secret=JqQX2PNo9bpM0uEihUPzyrh    // NOTE: Only required for web apps. This secret needs to be URL-Encoded.
```

What you have used is [Client credentials flow get token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token), in which you don't need the `code`.